# Как удалять несколько обьектов Range-based цикл

Tags: c++

Почему происходит ошибка? КомпилЯтор ругается, не могу удалить от начала списка до текущего эллемента? Как исправить?

```
std::vector<Location> route;

for (auto & r : route)
    for (auto & l : locs)
        if (l.enable && l == r) 
            route.erase(route.begin(), r); //<- Ошибка
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Вставьте ее в вопрос

Comment: `r` - не итератор а ссылка на элемент. это разные вещи. но даже если бы был итератором, стал бы не валидным при первом же удалении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть две ошибки:

1) vector::erase принимает пару итераторов, а вы пытаететсь передать итератор + значение переменной.

2) Range-base цикл, на самом деле, цикл опирающейся на итераторы, и в качестве скрытой переменной "текущая позиция" также используется итератор. В тоже время vector::erase инвалидирует все итераторы контейнера, а не только те, которые указывают на удаляемые элементы, как вы, вероятно думаете.

Возможные решения:
 Заменить range-based цикл на цикл с явным итератором, а кроме того, заменить тип контейнера с vector на lis.

Либо заменить range-based цикл на вызов стандартных алгоритмов:

```
auto condition=[&locs]( const Location& r)->bool{
   for (auto & l : locs)
       if (l.enable && l == r)         
          return true;
   return false;
}
route.erase( route.rend(), std::find_if( route.rbegin(), route.rend() , condition ));
```

Comment: стоит добавить, что если нужно удалить несколько элементов, то лучше использовать `erase-remove`, а если нужно удалить от `k` до `n`, то достаточно простого `erase(first, last)`